# ADO.net source giving error DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR in SSIS

Tags: ado.net, ssis, odbc

Here's the full error message:

> [ADO NET Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "ADO NET Source"
>   (1)" failed because error code 0x80131937 occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "output column "Z_ID" (16)" specifies failure on error.
>   An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

Comment: The message says "There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure." Is there any additional information you can provide?

Answer (score 3):

Breaking down the error message you have:

> The "component "ADO NET Source" (1)"
>   failed because error code 0x80131937
>   occurred,

Your ADO data source encountered an error and because you have specified the component should fail on errors (usually the default option) you get this part of the error message:

> ...the error row disposition on
>   "output column "Z_ID" (16)" specifies
>   failure on error.

Therefore your entire package has failed.

Have you recently installed the .NET framework on the same machine as you are running SSIS? If so a possible solution is provided by this MS Fix:

[Error message when you run a SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, or SQL Server 2008 R2 Integration Services package (SSIS) after you install the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1: "ADO NET Source [1424]"](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;969845&sd=rss&spid=13165)

I also came across [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/dcefa370-82c8-4aea-85be-892bdf49a304) which contains a post stating:

> In a nutshell, the cause of the
>   problem is that .net 2.0 isn't forward
>   compatible with .net 3.X.  what this
>   means is that applications that are
>   written to target .net 2.0 won't work
>   in a .net 3.X environment.  an ssis
>   2005 package is just another .net 2.0
>   application, so it won't work in a
>   .net 3.5 environment.  fyi: this is
>   also why ssis 2005 packages won't work
>   in ssis 2008 unless they're upgraded.

Comment: me getting similar error. I am working on upgrade from 2005 to 2008, what should i do so error is avoided.

Comment: @Pritesh - You would need to provide more information about your particular problem before I could answer. I recommend you post your own question, linked to this one, with as much information as you can provide. The short answer might be to rebuild your SSIS package in 2008 from scratch; which is only an option if the package is not too large.